# Flexbox margins in a grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a grid in flexbox, like so:

[image: flexbox grid]

They're all positioned using flexbox, and then the panels themselves (the coloured bits) have `margin: 5px`.

codepen here: https://codepen.io/callumacrae/pen/bRoZdp

Because the top right section has two elements, there's more margin there, so it's pushing down slightly—I don't want this to happen!

I guess the two possible fixes are either to make the margins not do that, or make the components five pixels *smaller* instead of five pixels larger like they are right now - but I don't know how to do either of those things.

How can I make adding more elements not change the size of the parent?

Comment: You need to use a horizontal layout instead of a vertical, as it will make row's equal height. If to keep vertical, you need to give each block a height

Comment: That only works in the simple case I posted - in more complicated cases (such as a vertical layout inside a horizontal layout, instead of the vertical layout), will still be an issue.

Comment: @callumacrae Why not using grid layout for this? I think in current case it's more appropriate.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov it's entirely inappropriate to use any feature that only has 69.3% browser support on a production website. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that you are sizing the elements using `flex-grow`. `flex-grow` is not the right property as it, together with `flex-shrink` is used to distribute the space left (or if to little).

You should use `flex-basis`, because as soon as you start fill these empty boxes with content, and their content will differ in size, they will misalign even more.

Here is an updated version of yours, where I changed to `style="flex-basis: calc(50% - 10px);"` (the 10px is to make up for your margins).

- [Codepen with `flex-basis`](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zzpVVa?editors=1000)

And here is a version of yours, with the same text I used in mine

- [Codepen with `flex-grow`](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WOdVvp)

Comment: Amazing! Thank you - will test and mark as solution when it works.